# lua string.upper not working with accented characters?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to convert some French text to upper case in lua, it is not converting the accented characters. Any idea why?

test script:

> print('échelle')
>       print(string.upper('échelle'))
>       print('ÉCHELLE')
>       print(string.lower('ÉCHELLE'))

output:

> échelle
>       éCHELLE
>       ÉCHELLE
>       Échelle

Answer (score 4):

It might be a bit overkill, but you can do this with [slnunicode](http://luaforge.net/projects/sln/) (which is available in LuaRocks).

```
require "unicode"
print(unicode.utf8.upper("échelle"))
-- ÉCHELLE
```

You may need to use `unicode.ascii.upper` or `unicode.latin1.upper` depending on the encoding of your source files.

Comment: The OP seems to be using Latin 1.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a suitable locale, which depends how these strings are encoded in the source.
You seem to be using Latin 1 because of the output you gave.
In this case, trying adding the line below at the top of your script:

`os.setlocale("fr_FR.ISO8859-1")`

This name is for Mac OS X. For Linux, try

`os.setlocale("fr_FR.iso88591")`

If you're using UTF, then setting a locale won't help because `string.lower` converts the string one byte at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Lua just uses the C library function `toupper`, which AFAIK [doesn't support accented characters](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2006-03/msg02572.html). You'd need to write a routine for that yourself.

Comment: Lua's `toupper` supports locales, which is different from encodings.

Answer (score 0):

To explain this all more effectively, Lua does not have built-in support for non-ASCII strings. You can store a Latin-1 or UTF-8-encoded string, but none of the special string manipulation functions (`upper`, `lower`, etc) will work on any non-ASCII character.

There are Lua libraries that add varying degrees of Unicode support. So you will have to use one of them.

Comment: This is not quite true. `string.lower` uses C's `tolower`, which depends on the current locale. But I guess this implies that it will work for  Latin-1 encoded strings but not for UTF-8-encoded strings if accented letters take more than one byte.

Comment: @lhf: There is no guarantee that the current local (which is platform-specific) understands Latin-1 or UTF-8 or any specific encoding.